# Android- Not getting full response from HttpResponse

Tags: android, get, android-asynctask, httpresponse

I am trying to get an HttpResponse in xml but Im not getting the whole response, what is courious is that if I loop the request the response ends in different parts but is never full.

I use the same code to request things from different Urls but I only get problems with one.

Here is the code of the AsyncTask:

```
public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, HttpResponse> {

private AsyncTaskListener listener;


@Override
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
    String link = params[0];
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(link);
    AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
    try {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request).;
        return httpResponse;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
    client.close();
}
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse result) {
    if (result != null){
        try {
            String sRes = EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity());
            listener.onNTCompleted(sRes);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public NetworkTask(AsyncTaskListener listener){
    this.listener=listener;
 }
}
```

Comment: did you solved yoyr problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps you but you have a problem because `EntityUtils.toString()` reads data from the network stream, which should not be done on UI thread (onPostExecute).  Try moving `EntityUtils.toString()` to `doInBackground()` first.  This may not help solve your problem, but it is the right thing to do.

Comment: thanks, you are right, this does not solve the problem though.